# Is there a way to implement custom SessionTrackingMode for servlet-app

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

I have a legacy servlet application running in Apache Tomcat. The app uses session to store some data between requests. Session data is stored with REDIS by [session manager](https://github.com/pivotalsoftware/session-managers) but cookie JSESSIONID is still used in session tracking.

I would like to integrate this app into microservice environment, where Bearer token authentication is used.

Is there a way to use a subj from token as session id instead of generated/passed via cookie value?

I found session id extraction in   `org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter#postParseRequest`

```java
// Look for session ID in cookies and SSL session
parseSessionCookiesId(request);
parseSessionSslId(request);

sessionID = request.getRequestedSessionId();
```